# Elements from List are not written to the textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I added elements to the List in Form2, but when I try to output them in Form1 textBox nothing happened.
I also put `public static List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();` in Program.cs .

```
    List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Basket e in sas)
        {
            basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

When I delete `List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();` from Form1, I have an error - "sas" name does not exist in this context.
So, how to make a list accessible from all forms?

Comment: `List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();` is a new and empty list. You don't see anything because there is nothing to write inside. As soon as you fill your list (before the loop!), you will be able to see something. Don't forget to set the `MultiLine` property to true in `basketBox`

Comment: how can you create instance of static ?

Comment: How to make a list accessible from all forms? I tried to make it public static in Program.cs but it doesn`t help.

Comment: "How to make a list accessible from all forms?" why in Program.cs ? you can leave it in your form and then use `Form2.sas`

Comment: "you can leave it in your form and then use Form2.sas" I have 9 Forms, and in every Form i output content from list and can fill this List. So I need only 1 list for all Forms.

Comment: And I tried to create public static List in another files, and it doesn`t help.

Comment: "So I need only 1 list for all Forms" and " I tried to create public static List in another files," if you need only 1 list, why did you create the lists in another forms? use the one list in all forms, delete the others

Comment: "use the one list in all forms, delete the others" i dont know how to do this

Comment: I make it public static, but It doesn't work and i can't use it in all forms

Comment: " i can't use it in all forms " show us this code please? "" delete the others" i dont know how to do this" remove the code!

Comment: I add Basket before sas in foreach and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you're using an empty list created in Form1 instead of the static list from Form2.
You should try:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach(Basket e in Form2.sas)
    {
        basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For solving this problem, I needed to wrote Basket.sas in foreach, not just sas.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill your list with data from your Form2. Try something like:

```
List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();
sas = yourListInForm2;
```